# Winforms binding causing no radio button to be left selected

Tags: c#, winforms

**Background**

In this winforms app, there are two radio buttons that I'm attempting to bind to properties on a model class.

**Code**

Related properties on the Model:

```
private bool _bTotalRowsLinear;
private bool _bTotalRowsLog;

public bool bTotalRowsLinear
    {
        get { return _bTotalRowsLinear; }
        set { _bTotalRowsLinear = value; }
    }

public bool bTotalRowsLog
    {
        get { return _bTotalRowsLog; }
        set { _bTotalRowsLog = value; }
    }
```

Code to create the bindings:

```
rdbTotalRowsLinear.DataBindings.Add("Checked",
                            objModel,
                            "bTotalRowsLinear",
                            false,
                            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

rdbTotalRowsLog.DataBindings.Add("Checked",
                            objModel,
                            "bTotalRowsLog",
                            false,
                            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

**Issue**
The initial binding works correctly. However, when I attempt to select the nonselected radio option, I first end up with *neither* radio button selected, forcing the user to click their desired option twice.

Initial State:

[image: Initial State]

After Clicking Once (error state):

[image: Error State]

Full code available on Github: https://github.com/nickheidke/datavelocityvisualizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, set the opposites, eg

```
set {
_bTotalRowsLinear = value;
_bTotalRowsLog = !bTotalRowsLinear;
}
...

set {
 _bTotalRowsLog = value; 
 _bTotalRowsLinear = !bTotalRowsLog;
}
```

Comment: That works great, but why should you have to do that? It also breaks down if you have more than 2 radio buttons in a group... Seems like a kludgy work around for a deeper problem.